# Display Pkg Version in Template

Tags: angular

I'm working in an Angular project. I know I can display the version of the app (from package.json), but I'm wanting to display the version of a pkg the app is using (that's under the dependencies.)

Is there a way to show that?
And on top of that, if I have the version set to get the latest minor and/or patch (with ~ or ^), am I able to grab the version of the pkg that was installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

In your `enviornment.ts` file do the following:

```
const packageJson = require('../../package.json');

export const environment = {
    ...
    versions: {
        app: packageJson.version,
        angular: packageJson.dependencies['@angular/core'],     
        rxjs: packageJson.dependencies.rxjs,
        ngxtranslate: packageJson.dependencies['@ngx-translate/core'],      
        angularCli: packageJson.devDependencies['@angular/cli'],
        typescript: packageJson.devDependencies['typescript'],
        cypress: packageJson.devDependencies['cypress']
    }
};
```

Then just import the `env` wherever you need it and use it like this:

```
import { environment as env } from '../../../environments/environment';

env.versions.angular
```

Comment: This works great, and I found that if you want to get version from the package-lock instead, you can by requiring that file (`const packageLockJson = require("../../package-lock.json");`) and then referencing that dependency (`packageLockJson.dependencies["{{dependency-name}}"].version`)